# How to use the OneNote API

Tags: api, onenote

Any body has already worked on Microsoft OneNote API?

What was the purpose for which you have used the OneNote API? I need some reference for the same and any reference to any good article will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

I worked with the API for some side Projects do make my life easier, it is very easy to use. What Platform are you Targeting? I started here: [Getting started with the OneNote API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575425.aspx) and this also helped me a lot [Documentation](http://dev.onenote.com/docs#/reference)